# Custom variables don't show for kGANPageScope?

Tags: ios, google-analytics-api

I'm tracking custom variables in my app using the three different scopes as seen in the code below. However, when I look at my reports inside Analytics only "Visitor" and "Session" scope variables show up. Page variables don't seem to get recorded (i.e. "myCustomVariable1" and "myCustomVariable2" never show up. It's my first time implementing this API, so I must be missing something.

```
NSString *deviceModel = [[UIDevice currentDevice]model];
NSString *systemVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion];

if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] setCustomVariableAtIndex:1
                                                         name:@"DeviceModel"
                                                        value:deviceModel
                                                        scope:kGANVisitorScope 
                                                    withError:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"error in setCustomVariableAtIndex");
    }

if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] setCustomVariableAtIndex:1
                                                         name:@"SystemVersion"
                                                        value:systemVersion
                                                        scope:kGANSessionScope 
                                                    withError:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"error in setCustomVariableAtIndex");
    }

NSString *myCustomVariable1 = @"myCustomVariable1";

if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] setCustomVariableAtIndex:1
                                                         name:@"myCustomVariable1"
                                                        value:myCustomVariable1
                                                        scope:kGANPageScope
                                                    withError:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"error in setCustomVariableAtIndex");
    }

NSString *myCustomVariable2 = @"myCustomVariable2";


    if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] setCustomVariableAtIndex:2
                                                         name:@"myCustomVariable2"
                                                        value:myCustomVariable2 
                                                        scope:kGANPageScope
                                                    withError:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"error in setCustomVariableAtIndex");
    }
```

Comment: are you tracking page views or events ?

Comment: if I want to know when a form is submitted or cancelled, is that a page view or event?